# General github usage

Tags: github, clone, fork, fetch

I created a directory called spring labs on one machine then pushed it to a repository on github, now I want to download the entire repository onto another machine. I am following the steps for forking to do this I have cloned it then fetched the upstream but I don't understand how I get the directory onto my machine to edit the files and be able to push back to the repository, I don't fully grasp github yet.

Comment: You need to read up on git, not github...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's assume you have a repository called `Blah` on Github. Furthermore, let's assume this repo contains the files you wish to work on, etc.

On the machine you wish to *download* your repository onto, do the following:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:anderskitson/Blah.git
$ cd Blah
```

Now all your files *should* be available in the `Blah` subdirectory.

Now assume you've made and commited all your changes. How would you push them *back* up to Github?

```
$ cd Blah
$ git commit -am 'This is my commit message.'
$ git push origin master
```

This assumes that the *name* of the branch you wish to push back up is `master`.

Comment: ok when i type Anderss-MacBook-Pro:springlabs anderskitson$ ls I see all the files. But I can't for the life of me find the spring labs folder anywhere in the finder.

Comment: @AndersKitson You are doing this from the _terminal_, correct? If so, just run the `pwd` command and it should print out exactly where your are. Then navigate to that directory in Finder.

Comment: puts it in a hidden .ssh directory thats why. Thanks Marvin.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am just going to use this to clone it and it should do what i think
http://mac.github.com/
It is cloning right now I will check back later.